# Compiler Error: "Default Initialization of an Object..." using CodeLite

Tags: c++, codelite

Trying to run the following Code and keep getting back the error message:
"Default initialization of an object on const type 'const double'

Following a tutorial and everything w/in seems to match up but the code won't compile to run for some reason.

Here's my Code:

```
// Section 11
// Function Definitions
// Area of Circle and Volume of a Cylinder
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const double pi{3.14159};

double calc_area_circle(double radius) {
    return pi * radius * radius;
}


void area_circle() {
    double radius{};
    cout << "\nEnter the radius of the circle: ";
    cin >> radius;
    cout << "The area of a circle with radius " << radius << " is " << calc_area_circle(radius) << endl;

}


int main() {

    area_circle();
    //volume_cylinder();


    return 0;
}
```

[Screenshot of IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lguFv.png)

Comment: What C++ standard are you compiling to?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list 

The brace-init-list is only available since C++ 11. Try building with flag -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11

Comment: Or change to const double pi= 3.14159;

Comment: You can also use the pi constant as explained here https://www.codespeedy.com/pi-constant-in-cpp/

Comment: Tried setting it to C++11 Standard in CodeLite.  Then tried to build the project and received the same error message =(

Comment: Bummer. What you have should work in C++11. Make sure there are no un-printable, invisible characters hidden in there after, for example, a copy-paste from a not-supported wide character source.

Comment: @Eyal D, it's not a brace-init-list, it's uniform initialization

Comment: I figured It out!  Thx for your help guys.  Even though I set up my IDE to build my code with C++11 standard in general during initial set up it wasn't doing it for this project for some reason.  Had to manually set this specific project to C++11/14/17 standard for it to compile correctly.